# source is missing when debugging maven build configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven-3, m2eclipse

I have a `maven build` run configuration which I use to start tomcat server. Barely this is `tomcat:run` command which is executed by m2eclipse plugin.

That was all fine until I needed to jump into spring source code. I can not set source code lookup for debugger!!! All jars have their source code location setup, so I can open spring classes by `Ctrl+click`. But debugger seems does not understand this settings, I tried to add project to source code lookup, but that worked only for code that is in that project and not in its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Try Igor's [source lookup feature](https://github.com/ifedorenko/com.ifedorenko.m2e.sourcelookup), it will help you get jar sources automatically during external process execution (maven plugin invocation, in your case).